# How to select a selected element in jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
$('#something').click(function() {
    //select the same element that was clicked and slide it down
});
```

Is it possible in jquery to select the same element that the function is working with without actually slecting it again?

Comment: are you looking to `$(this)` inside the callback?

Comment: is there an element `id="something"` in your html and you want to scroll to it?

Comment: thanks @Sirko. Exactly what I was looking for

Comment: You can extract the object as a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should work.
The rest is plain css.
If you talk about scrolling, you can achieve this with some Javascript.

```
$('#something').click(function() {
    //select the same element that was clicked and slide it down
    $(this).toggleClass('slideMeDown');
});
```